# Monitor resolution through terminal

Tags: resolution, monitor, display-resolution

How can I force Ubuntu to apply a specific monitor resolution through terminal?

In my case I have a monitor of resolution 1600*900@60fps but Ubuntu shows only two resolutions both awkwardly lower than the monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when I ran xrandr command I got the result and a virtual display was shut down and the native resolution came into effect!!

Don't know how it happened but it became fine!